# Android Studio - create remote branch from local

Tags: android, git, android-studio

Is it possible to **push local commit as new remote branch** or **make local branch as remote one** in Android Studio? And how? I know how to do that using console. Just wondering is there any possibility to do that in Android Studio.

There are no problems creating local branches from remote using "Checkout as new local branch" but how could you do exactly vice versa?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> push local commit as new remote branch

Yes, it is possible.

In below figure, click underlined `develop` branch name and give new name.

It will show `+` sign with name if remote branch is not existed.
Then, Android Studio automatically creates new remote branch with given name.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! No idea why developers of studio made such an unobvious way to do that. You saved my project :)

Comment: @AnZ // glad to help you to enjoy developing. Please mark as answer if you solve your issue :)

Comment: @AshishShukla you would be able to select remote branch during push. Click on underscored name and there will be options